# Date formatting returning wrong value and format

Tags: vba, date, excel

i'm having a strange issue. for some reason that i cannot comprehend this simple little bit of code is returning the wrong value. it is returning 3/8/1985. if i do the formatting as "mm/dd/yy" it returns the correct date, that is in a format that i don't want. (just as a note if i use "mm" in the formatting it returns 1/2/1900, and if i use "mmdd" it returns 11/6/1900.) this was working properly before, so i assume that something must have changed, but i have no idea what.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub testdate()    
Dim today As Date
today = Format(Now, "mmddyy")    
MsgBox today    
End Sub
```

Comment: use `Dim today As String` instead `Dim today As Date`. Or use  direct `MsgBox Format(Now, "mmddyy")` instead `MsgBox today`

Comment: ah-ha, thanks, i should have seen that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub testdate()
    Dim todayy As String
    todayy = Format(Now, "mmddyy")
    MsgBox todayy
End Sub
```

will display **031114**